BMO norm of |f|^(1/2)
I am not sure if it is right that $$\||f|^{1/2}\|_{BMO}\leq\|f\|_{BMO}$$  (Please prove it or provide a counterexample. And I think it will be right if we replace RHS by $2\|f\|_{BMO}$)
$$\|f\|_{BMO}=\mathop{sup}\limits_{Q}\frac{1}{|Q|}\int_{Q}|f-f_{Q}|$$

This is not a homework service

It is not from homework.In fact, the proposition is given in a class if the RHS is replaced by 2||f||_{BMO}, but I can't find a counterexample of the stronger constant
